# gauss jordan pivot in javascript simplex method

Tags: javascript, math, gaussian, simplex

I have read and analyzed the source code [here](http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html) for my problem:

I find it difficult to pivot this 5x8 matrix which is contained in a 2D array. Can someone help and explain the steps on this? Different sources show different solutions. But the cited link above is the output I want to achieve. Codes are pretty appreciated :)

BTW, I am making a simplex method in pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

better read than the forementioned link
[The Simplex Method: Solving Standard Maximization Problems](http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/tutorialsf4/frames4_3.html)